# C# code fetching cached version of data from FTP

Tags: c#, .net, iis, ftp

In my project I am downloading few files from a ftp created over IIS7 and also over linux server and saving it to my Appdata/Roamingfolder. Problem is coming when either I modify the content of the csv file or simply deleting the old file and replacing it with new file with same name but modified content.

Every time i have to rename that file and downloading the renamed file works. This indicates its downloading some cached image of the file which i am unable to locate either on my local system as well as over ftp server.

```
public static bool FTPFileDownload(string strFolderName, string 
pathToStore, bool blIsSingleFile = true, string strFileType = "")
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(pathToStore))
            {
                // Try to create the directory.
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToStore);
            }
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPUrl"].ToString() + strFolderName);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPUser"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPPassword"].ToString());
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            request.Proxy = null;
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            System.Collections.Generic.List<string> directories = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();

            string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            {
                //If extension is available match with extension and add.
                bool blAddFile = false;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strFileType))
                {
                    string strExt = Path.GetExtension(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPUrl"].ToString() + line).Remove(0, 1);
                    if (strExt.ToLower() == strFileType.ToLower())
                        blAddFile = true;
                }
                else
                    blAddFile = true;

                if (blAddFile)
                {
                    directories.Add(line);
                }
                line = streamReader.ReadLine();
            }
            streamReader.Close();

            using (WebClient ftpClient = new WebClient())
            {
                ftpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPUser"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPPassword"].ToString());

                for (int i = 0; i <= directories.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (directories[i].Contains("."))
                    {
                        string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPUrl"].ToString() + strFolderName
                            + (blIsSingleFile ? "" : "/" + directories[i].ToString());

                        string trnsfrpth = pathToStore + directories[i].ToString();
                        ftpClient.DownloadFile(path, trnsfrpth);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            FileLogger.logMessage(ex.Message);
            if (FileLogger.IsDebuggingLogEnabled)
            {
                FileLogger.HandleError("FTPFileDownload", ex, "Common Helper Error 4:");
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I don't know what is going wrong with it. Either my code is wrong or the settings or environment over ftp server.

Please suggest.

Comment: Because you're doing it via a webversion of ftp, perhaps you have a proxy server that has cached it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Posting a dump of your code and stating "it doesn't work" isn't helping anyone to help you.

Comment: If you download the file with a regular FTP client, do you get an up-to-date copy?

Comment: @BugFinder What do you mean by *"webversion of ftp"*?

Comment: @ChrisPickford I am not getting any lead as what else can be done. tried searching over net first ,didn't found any relevant suggestion. have tried to remove and create fresh ftp over server. strange thing is this code is working fine when i tried creating ftp over my local system but over server locations this is an issue.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl if I am accessing the ftp file through browser by simply firing URL over it, I am getting the updated file. but not with my code.

Comment: What URL? `ftp://` or `http://`?